# Casperjs iframe not loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to load a page with a iframe via casperjs.

```
casper.then(function () {
    this.page.switchToChildFrame(0);
    var dom = this.evaluate(function() {
         return document.querySelector("html").innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(dom);
}
```

`switchToChildFrame` works but I only get a head and body, but the body has no content.

Comment: Is this works ? `document.querySelector(":root")`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> **You need to use `withFrame` function:**
>
> ```
> casper.then(function (){
>     this.wait(3000,function(){//You probably need to wait until iframe is loaded.
>     this.withFrame(1,function(){
>          var dom = this.evaluate(function() {
>          return document.querySelector("html").innerHTML;
>          });
>          console.log(dom);
>          });
>          });
>      });
> ```